# Create grid of images with increasing grey scale values

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some C++ to create a 1048x1048x8 bit matrix of 256x256 squares. The first should have a grey scale value of 0 while the last should be 255. This is what I've tried so far. Any feedback is appreciated.
First image is my result. Second is the desired.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmGOZ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMpi1.png

```
using namespace std;

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


int main() 
{
    char img[256][256];
    ofstream binaryFile("file.raw", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!binaryFile) {
        cout << "cannot create file";
        return 1;
    }
    //create raw file 
    char color = 0;

    //nested for loops to iterate the pixel with varying grey scale values
    for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                img[i][j] = color;
            }
        }
        color = color + 15;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            img[0][i] = 0;
            img[i][0] = 0;
            img[255][i] = 0;
            img[i][255] = 0;
        }
        



        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                binaryFile.write((char*)&img[i][j], sizeof(img[i][j]));
            }
        }
    }
    // end raw file editing
    binaryFile.close();
    if (!binaryFile.good()) {
        cout << "Error occurred at writing time!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since C++ has no concept of graphics, you're going to need a graphics library.  You may want to consider writing a Windowing program instead of a console.

Comment: Check the graphics library to see if it has support for images.  If not, you'll need a library for processing image formats.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks. I am supposed to write a console app and process the image through this program. https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/

Comment: You have 3 cascaded for loops with 16x256x256 iterations. That is too many. Either go through the image with 256x256 iterations and calculate for each pixel the grayscale or go blickwise with 16x64x64 iterations and calculate the target coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So each row of pixels (from left to right) spans **4** different colored squares (**4** columns using **x**), and each square is **256** pixels wide:

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
        // write one pixel here
    }
}
```

Each column of pixels (from top to bottom) also spans **4** different colored squares (**4** rows using **y**), and each square is **256** pixels high:

```cpp
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        // inner loop here
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is to determine the color of each square. The color should advance 1 "increment" of 17 (max color / number of increments = 255 / 15) for each row. And each row should advance the color 4 "increments" of 17.

Now i hear you say, **17**? That can't be right. Just hold on a bit longer.

For each column **x**, increment by **1**. And for each row **y**, increment by **4**. That comes down to: `x + ( y * 4 )`. Apply the increment **17** like we said before, and you get: `( x + ( y * 4 ) ) * 17`. Since the `*` takes precedence over `+`, the internal brackets `( )` are not needed, leaving just: `(x+y*4)*17`.

That will make the colors for each square look like this:

|  | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Row 0** | 0 | 17 | 34 | 51 |
| **Row 1** | 68 | 85 | 102 | 119 |
| **Row 2** | 136 | 153 | 170 | 187 |
| **Row 3** | 204 | 221 | 238 | 255 |

See? Nicely spaced colors, starting on 0 and ending on 255.

Putting it all together:

```cpp
for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            char color = (x+y*4)*17;
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                binaryFile.put(color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Pixel data is written in order of rows. So writing blocks of 256x256 will not do the job. (You can consider this by thinking img[256][256] same as img[256*256]). To make this right, you must write a first row of first 4 blocks, then a second row of first 4 blocks, etc... (Block here means 256x256 section).

I think this code should do:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 1024; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 1024; ++col) {

        // the part ((row / 256) * 4 + (col / 256)) will go from 0 to 15
        unsigned char color = ((row / 256) * 4 + (col / 256)) * 16;
        
        if (row % 256 == 0 || col % 256 == 0) {
            // This will not draw last border
            color = 0;
        }
        // If you need last border uncomment below, but will reduce last block size by one
        /*
        if (row == 1024 - 1 || col == 1024 - 1) {
            color = 0;
        }
        */
        binaryFile.write((char*) &color, sizeof(color));
    }
}
```